# how to add custom taxonomies value from fronted

Tags: wordpress

I am building a  template of fronted  post.
i want add custom  taxonomies value from fronted in adding post from fronted 
how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add taxonomy term (value) using following WordPress function:

`<?php wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() ); ?>`

For more info on function and its parameters 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term